# First Responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new to i-phone development and any body can Explain me what is First Responder in IB.where can i use this in IB and what is the use..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this previous answer: [The concept of file's owner,first responder, and application delegate in iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305183/the-concept-of-files-owner-first-responder-and-application-delegate-in-iphone/2305475#2305475)

You can also search for "First responder" in SO. There was many subjects

Answer (score 0):

Every nib file has atleast two files; File's Owner and First Responder which cannot be deleted. File's Owner simply shows that it owns the object in the nib file. First Responder tells us which object are we currently interacting with; like the textbox, buttons...