# Auto-resize iPhone xib app to ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib

I built an iPhone app "using xib" with 5-6 screens. Now I want to auto-resize the display for iPad. I am using xcode 4.6.

Do I have to rebuild the entire code using storyboards? It will be a very tedious work. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout?

Comment: No, Auto-layout is unchecked. If I use Auto-Layout, code will crash in device or if i try to run in old version simulator

Comment: storyboard is a nice option for managing ipad or iphone xib's if device > iOS5

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Interface Builder and Delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761814/iphone-interface-builder-and-delegates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create only new xib files for iPad and name them as `ViewController_iPhone.xib` and `ViewController_iPad.xib` and when switching your views, just put a simple condition

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                 @"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                 @"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: putting this `if-else` condition everywhere is not cumbersome?

Answer (score 3):

use autolayout and everything will be done automatically

[image]

if not `autolayout`, then making 2 `xib` will be a better option. Make `ipad` size `xib` with the same name and put `~ipad` after classname.

Like if you `xib` name is `myClass.xib` and create other one like `myClass~ipad.xib`.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran : I am not using autolayout and using separate xibs for iphone and ipad by using ~iphone and ~ipad suffixes in the names of the xibs. My question is can I use some suffix like ~-568h for longer iPhone screens like that of iPhone 5?